# tree collapsible d3.js agrandar tamaño de forma automática al colocar div dentro, agregar acciones a menú contextual y crear margen entre nodos

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Soy nuevo en d3.js y estoy usando la librería d3 v3 pero no es una restricción se puede responder con la versión 5 o 4 pero no menor a la 3. Por lo general no necesito pregunatar cuando tengo que hacer algo pero en hacer preguntas y d3.js soy novato.

favor implementar las modificaciones a este código y de forma que sea facil de implementar y modificar
[Código fuente aquí](https://codepen.io/20141778p2/pen/VqxaGw)

1. Quiero separar los nodos de su punto de intersección
   Ejemplo de código (obviar funcionalidad jquery) [ver aquí](https://codepen.io/20141778p2/pen/ZVxZVy)
   que cando una finalize el otro inicio "var pixel = 10px" después de lo que indique la variable. Extraido de [aquí](https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460)
2. Tamaño auto ajustable al contenido y que se puedan agregar si se le agregan varios div dentro y que sea de forma automática y por transición (esto se vincula a la 3).
3. Agregar funcionalidad al menú contextual y los div que se puedan agregar de la petición 2 se puedan hacer desde el menú contextual, al igual que un una opción para hacer acercamiento.
   [Código ejemplo aquí](https://codepen.io/20141778p2/pen/vvRMjv), extraído de [aquí](http://jsfiddle.net/1mo3vmja/109)